# Glassware Test Instruments CAD blocks library

Tags: analytical-chemistry, equipment

I am designing a fairly simple distillation for dichloromethane.
Being an engineer I feel more comfortable working with precise dimensions of both the separate glass vessels (condensers, evaporators, flask, etc) and of the complete apparatus.

I have been looking to find a CAD library that has various glassware blocks. 
This way I can visually assemble my set and be able to show a drawing to my supervisor.

Comment: What are you trying to separate dichloromethane from? At what scale? If the distillation is *simple*, then there is no need for you to reinvent the wheel and design your own system. Depending on the scale and the impurities, there is likely an extant system (or several) that you could use.

Comment: I am dissolving <1g of tars in about 400ml of DCM.
Where might I find examples of such systems?