# Where can I find CAD blocks for lab glassware?

Tags: reference-request, equipment

I want to draw a sketch of my apparatus for my report. I am conversant with the AutoCAD drafting software. Where can I download CAD blocks for commonly used labware items (like round bottom flask, allihn condensor, drying tube, heating mantle, retort stand, etc.)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/glassware-test-instruments-cad-blocks-library

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing out that one, but I see there are no answers to that question too.

Comment: @Todd I don't think it makes sense to close a question as a duplicate of an unanswered one.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M - Agreed, and my bad for not following up. Let's keep it open.

Comment: @Abhishek - does it have to be CAD? Found [this](https://www.edrawsoft.com/laboratory-equipment.php) which looks more like UML but might be of use.

Comment: @Todd, yeah it will "work" for the time being, but drawing custom made modified glassware items is very simple in CAD...anyway thanks!

Answer (score 3):

ChemDraw has a couple of templates with all kinds of laboratory glasswere.
Here is a screenshot of some of the possibilities: [image: Clipwere selection from ChemDraw Professional 15.1]
[image: Clipwere selection from ChemDraw Professional 15.1]